# Report Builder 3.0: How to convert string representation of dates in mm/dd/yy format using CDate

Tags: date, reporting-services, reportbuilder, string-conversion, regional-settings

I'm building a report using Report Builder 3.0.

The source system I'm working with has strings representing dates in the format of `mm/dd/yy`, but I want to show this to the end users as `dd-MMM-yy` instead. Using `CDate` on the string will give me errors because it's interpreting the string in the `dd/mm/yy` format (US regional settings).

Is there a way to convert the string to a date correctly without changing the regional settings (this isn't really an option)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `Format` command and specify the exact format you require. For example:

```
=Format(Cdate(Fields!Date.Value),"dd-MM-yyyy")
```

or you can try this:

```
=Day(Fields!Date.Value) & "/" & Month(Fields!Date.Value) & "/" & Year(Fields!Date.Value)
```

**EDIT:** This is OK:

```
=Cdate(Mid(Fields!Date.Value,4,2) & "/" & Mid(Fields!Date.Value,1,2) & "/" & Mid(Fields!Date.Value,7,4))
```

Comment: CDate will return an error if the Date field isn't in the "dd/mm/yyyy" format already. For example, if I have "01/15/2012", CDate will think that the month field is "15" and throw an error.

Comment: This gives the same result, because `Day`, `Month`, and `Year` are expecting the respective values to be "dd-mm-yyyy" format. `Month` will always check the middle part of the string for the month value...

Comment: Got it.So, the field you want to convert is a string? Why not manipulate it as a string to get what you want? Let's say you have a date "02/23/2011", I suggest you this: `Cdate(Mid(Fields!Date.Value,4,5) & "/" & Mid(Fields!Date.Value,1,2) & "/" & Mid(Fields!Date.Value,7,10))`

Comment: Just wanted to make an amendment: Mid(Fields!Date.Value,4,5) should actually be Mid(Fields!Date.Value,4,2) (same with the other Mid calls). The 3rd parameter is the number of characters to grab, not the ending position of the string.

Comment: YEs, you're right, sorry for that.I am editing the answer again, as you suggested. Sorry and thanks for pointing that!